# Python3 with setuptools fails copying data if run by checkinstall

Tags: python, python3

Running `checkinstall` for a python module which uses setuptools fails while `running install_data` with error: `error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` on the first file it encounters. It is creating directories successfully however.

Before that it successfully performs prior steps like `running install_lib`, `running build_py` and copies files for those steps just fine, but not for `running install_data`.

Should I change my system python from version 3 to version 2.7 - it does successfully build a package without errors.

Why does python3 fail to copy files if run by `checkinstall`, while 2.7 does not fail?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a known bug with checkinstall: https://bugtrack.izto.org:4442/show_bug.cgi?id=33

I got python 3.7.1 to work by passing `--fstrans=no` as suggested there.

Comment: The link in your answer does not open :(

Comment: It worked when I was looking at it... Seems like their entire bug tracker is down right now. Debian bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=717778 ubuntu bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/checkinstall/+bug/78455